# sqlexception 'timeout expired'?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-membership, authorization

I have some code in the global.asax file in my application. Each time I debug my website I get a `sqlexception` for some reason:

```
void Application_AuthorizeRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Membership.GetUser() != null && Roles.IsUserInRole("UnFilled")) // this is where I get the exception
    {
        if (Response.Cookies["Expiration"] == null)
        {
            HttpRequest request = Context.Request;
            HttpResponse response = Context.Response;
            response.ContentType = ".aspx";
            response.Write(request.Url.Host + "/Activate.aspx?account="+Membership.GetUser().Email);  
        }
    }      
}
```

anyone know why I get this, how can I solve it?

Comment: Does it work when you are not debugging? How have you implemented the membership provider? It is probably just a general connection issue.

Comment: Occasionaly it happens, and doesn't happen. And it works when I'm not debugging

Comment: Are you able to isolate if it is the Membership.GetUser() != null or the Roles.IsUserInRole("UnFilled") part of the if statement that is causing the exception. Are you able to temporarily move one of them to try and isolate the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer, but not sure why it works. It seems to work if I place the coding into a custom http handler.

Thanks to all that contributed.